# Dragging file onto document body triggers modal with Dropzone.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-modal, dropzone.js

I want to duplicate the behavior for uploading images in Slack in my chat app.

Currently, you can click a button in the area where you enter a message, and that brings up a modal where you can drag and drop files using Dropzone.js. That’s great.

However, I also want the entire page (document body) to be a dropzone as well. So when you drag a file onto the screen, I want the previously mentioned modal to pop up, with the dragged file loaded.

I tried adding this to the bottom of the page, but no dice:

```
<script>
    //    Make whole page a dropzone for image uploads
    new Dropzone("#body", { // Make the whole body a dropzone
        url: "/upload/url", // Set the url
        previewsContainer: "#modal-image-uploads .modal-body #previews" // Define the container to display the previews
    });

    Dropzone.options.filedrop = {
        init: function () {
            this.on("complete", function (file) {
                if (this.getUploadingFiles().length === 0 && this.getQueuedFiles().length === 0) {
                    $('body').append("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'rooms/modals/image_uploads') %>");
                }
            });
        }
    };
</script>
```

The error in the console is: Uncaught Error: Invalid `previewsContainer` option provided. Please provide a CSS selector or a plain HTML element.

Here's what the modal looks like:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-image-uploads" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Upload Image</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <div id="previews" class="dropzone-previews"></div>
                <form action="/file-upload"
                      class="dropzone"
                      id="my-awesome-dropzone"></form>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that "#modal-image-uploads .modal-body" is a valid selector to find your preview container?

Comment: Sorry. Realized a mistake and edited the question.

Comment: If you search the DOM before trying to upload a file, are you able to find this markup using that selector? This error will happen if the selector returns nothing, regardless of whether it is a valid selector provided or not.

Comment: Sorry for delay. No, it doesn't pick up that selector because the modal isn't loaded.